# Getting memory errors while running python in Window's Linux-subsytem

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am creating a raster region of interest from a shapefile using numpy, a very small region. However, when I run the file, I get a memory issue.
Where is the problem?

I have tried in different windows systems and it doesn't work.
However, it runs successfully in either a computer running Ubuntu as the only OS or a VirtualBox Ubuntu system.

```
    import os
    import sys
    import numpy as np
    from osgeo import gdal,ogr,osr


    def create_aoi_grid(inputAOI,outputGrid,gridSize):
        """
        FUNCTION: create_aoi_grid
        ARGUMENTS: inputAOI - input shapefile with SHP file extension
                   outputGrid - output raster grid with TIFF file extension
                   gridSize - output raster grid cell size in decimal degrees
        KEYWORDS: n/a
        RETURNS: n/a
        NOTES: Returns no variables but writes an output file
        """

        # try to do the process
        try:

            # define script file path for relative path definitions
            __location__ = os.path.realpath(
            os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))

            # Define pixel_size and NoData value of new raster
            NoData_value = 0

            #Define output coordinate system
            spatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
            spatialRef.SetWellKnownGeogCS('WGS_84')

            # Open the data source and read in the extent
            source_ds = ogr.Open(os.path.join(__location__,inputAOI))
            source_layer = source_ds.GetLayer()
            x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = source_layer.GetExtent()

            # Create high res source for boundary accuracy
            hiResRatio = 50.
            highResGrid = gridSize / hiResRatio

            # Get high res cell size
            x_hres = int(np.ceil((x_max - x_min) / highResGrid))
            y_hres = int(np.ceil((y_max - y_min) / highResGrid))

            # Create high res raster in memory
            mem_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM').Create('', x_hres, y_hres, gdal.GDT_Byte)
            mem_ds.SetGeoTransform((x_min, highResGrid, 0, y_max, 0, -highResGrid))
            band = mem_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
            band.SetNoDataValue(NoData_value)

            # Rasterize shapefile to high resolution grid
            gdal.RasterizeLayer(mem_ds, [1], source_layer, burn_values=[1])

            # Get rasterized high res shapefile
            array = band.ReadAsArray()

            # Flush memory file
            mem_ds = None
            band = None

            # Create the destination data source
            x_res = int(np.ceil((x_max - x_min) / gridSize))
            y_res = int(np.ceil((y_max - y_min) / gridSize))
            drv =  gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
            target_ds = drv.Create(os.path.join(__location__,outputGrid), x_res, y_res, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
            target_ds.SetGeoTransform((x_min, gridSize, 0, y_max, 0, -gridSize))
            target_ds.SetProjection(spatialRef.ExportToWkt())

            # Create blank mask array at target res
            outMask = np.zeros([y_res,x_res])

            # Loop over array to find the elements the high res raster falls in
            for i in range(y_res):
                y1 = int(i*hiResRatio)
                y2 = int(y1+hiResRatio)
                for j in range(x_res):
                    x1 = int(j*hiResRatio)
                    x2 = int(x1+hiResRatio)

                    tmp = array[y1:y2,x1:x2]

                    if np.any(tmp==1)==True:
                        outMask[i,j] = 1

            # set the mask array to the target file
            band = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
            band.WriteArray(outMask)
            band.SetNoDataValue(NoData_value)

            # Flush the target file
            target_ds = None
            band = None

        # if not working, then give an error message
        except AttributeError:
            raise IOError('Raster file input error, check that all paths are correct')

        return

    # Main level program for use in the command line
    def main():

        n_args = len(sys.argv)

        # Check user inputs
        if n_args != 4:
            print "Wrong user input"
            print "Script converts shapefile to raster grid"
            print "usage: python create_aoi_grid.py <input shapefile> <output raster file> <output cell size>"
            print "Exiting system..."
            sys.exit()

        else:
            # Pass command line arguments into function
            create_aoi_grid(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2],float(sys.argv[3]))

        return

    # Execute the main level program if run as standalone
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()

ERROR 2: memdataset.cpp, 1545: cannot allocate 13575538710083211 bytes
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "create_aoi_grid.py", line 135, in <module>
 main()
File "create_aoi_grid.py", line 129, in main
 create_aoi_grid(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2],float(sys.argv[3]))
File "create_aoi_grid.py", line 110, in create_aoi_grid
 raise IOError('Raster file input error, check that all paths are correct')
IOError: Raster file input error, check that all paths are correct
```

The output is a Raster.

Comment: Can you show us the script you are running here?

Comment: @ifconfig I have re-edited the post with the upper part as the code I am running and the lower part as the error I am getting